# How to get number of rows without SELECTING all rows?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, numbers, rows

How can i get the number of rows like `mysql_num_rows` but without having a mysql resource to work from, because i don't know the future scale of my webapp and it could take an hour just to get the number of rows ;)

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM tblName;` - and just retrieve `num_rows` column from that statement.

Answer (score 4):

Make an SQL query with [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html), e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ...
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count for differences between COUNT(*) and COUNT(id)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you have a LIMIT clause in your "actual" sql query *and* want to know the toal number of items (e.g. when doing some kind of pagination) you might also be interested in [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM table`

Will return 1 row with a field called number which holds the number of rows in the table.